# How to check memory leaks in ROS nodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to run valgrind in a somewhat complex node (an OMPL planner with Octomap and Actionlib). For this, I am running the node as:

`valgrind --log-file=test.txt --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./devel/lib/planner/planner goal_pose:=/move_base_simple/goal collision_map:=/octomap_full`

It runs so slow I cannot test anything without spending some hours (although it works fast when running without valgrind).

Anyway, if I close the node killing it (Ctrl+C), I get many errors in the valgrind report. Some of them are:

```
==3227== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3227==     in use at exit: 2,407,249 bytes in 85 blocks
==3227==   total heap usage: 1,713,622 allocs, 1,713,537 frees, 280,743,319 bytes allocated
==3227== 
==3227== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 12 of 82
==3227==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3227==    by 0x704D208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x704DDCA: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x704DE63: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x8733CF2: log4cxx::helpers::Transcoder::decode(std::string const&, std::string&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86EB77A: log4cxx::LogManager::getLogger(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86E6185: log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x81BEE79: ros::console::impl::initialize() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so)
==3227==    by 0x55C40B0: ros::console::initialize() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so)
==3227==    by 0x55C1DFC: ??? (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so)
==3227==    by 0x4010139: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:78)
==3227==    by 0x4010222: _dl_init (dl-init.c:36)
==3227== 
==3227== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 13 of 82
==3227==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3227==    by 0x704D208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x704E930: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x704ED47: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==3227==    by 0x86DCE10: log4cxx::Level::getAll() (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86D31E6: log4cxx::Hierarchy::Hierarchy() (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86EB4C4: log4cxx::LogManager::getLoggerRepository() (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86EB700: log4cxx::LogManager::getLoggerLS(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86EB785: log4cxx::LogManager::getLogger(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x86E6185: log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*) (in /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0)
==3227==    by 0x81BEE79: ros::console::impl::initialize() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so)
==3227==    by 0x55C40B0: ros::console::initialize() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so)
```

I cannot guess where do they come from, and if they are my fault. Therefore, my question is easy:

How do you guys check your nodes for memory leaks? Because valgrind slowdown+all these errors make it not very practical.

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213788/how-to-check-memory-leaks-in-ros-nodes/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you isolate the code you're developing to a more contained (unit) test that does not require deploying your entire system?. Otherwise, can you setup a simpler system test?.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-15**:
I thought about that, but that causes three issues IMO: it takes a lot of time to develop these tests and it does not guarantee that the integration of the "modules" will be free of leaks, as some errors can be done in the integration steps. 3) it is harder to maintain. But I guess I have no choice